# Trouble with TPageControl DrawTab

Tags: delphi, ownerdrawn, tpagecontrol

I set the TPageControl Style to Flat Buttons (`tsFlatButtons`), and change the tab's button color using the `OnDrawTab` event.

It works, but the button that is not-active has grey (btnFace color) border!
[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

```
procedure TForm1.PageControlDrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl;
          TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);

var
  AText: string;
  ARect: TRect;

begin
  with (Control as TPageControl).Canvas do
  begin
    ARect := Rect;
    OffsetRect(ARect, 0, 4);

    Brush.Color := COLOR1;
    FillRect(Rect);

    AText := TPageControl(Control).Pages[TabIndex].Caption;

    with Control.Canvas do   
      DrawText(Control.Canvas.Handle, PChar(AText), -1,ARect, DT_CENTER or DT_SINGLELINE);

  end;
end;
```

Comment: I added the code. It is pretty straight forward.

Comment: It worked fine for me. Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Also, which Windows version? Could be something to do with themes / common controls version...

Comment: I tested on XP Pro using Classic theme. Delphi is version 7.

Comment: @David: I wrote it works, but there is grey border. I will upload screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question with screenshot showing the grey border of the in-active tab button.

Comment: You have not shown all the code. Where does all that blue come from? What else have you done beyond the default page control?

Comment: The blue color = COLOR1 variable. You can change it to clBlue, it will have the same effect. As I wrote, the code is pretty straight forward: Add a TPageControl, add 2 tabs, set Style to Flat Buttons, and create that onDrawTab method. You will see the grey border effect.

Comment: It's not what I see. But I'm on 7. I guess you are choosing the blue color to match the particular XP theme you have.

Comment: Here: Create a new application, set the Form color to clBlue. Add TPageControl, set Style to Flat Buttons. Add 2 tabs. Set PageControl onDrawTab and change the tab button color.

Comment: I changed the XP theme to "XP", same problem.

Comment: Ah, form colour to blue! That's the missing step. I still think you'll need a full custom draw.

Comment: This problem was documented here as well: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/6/329345.html

Comment: Full custom draw? Oops ... I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, if the design is ok for you
[image]
, you can hide the current tabs:

```
  for I := 0 to Pred(PageControl1.PageCount) do
    PageControl1.Pages[I].TabVisible := False;
```

and add a **TTabSet**
with these properties:

```
BackgroundColor := clGradientActiveCaption;
SelectedColor := clGradientActiveCaption;
Style := tsModernTabs
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post but since it does not have a complete answer and I had the same problem and finally found out how to do it, I thought I should let you know...

Also your code does not work well if some of the tabs have tabvisible set to False
Here is I think the best way to fix this, using an integer i to loop the tabs:

```
for I := 0 to TPageControl(Control).PageCount-1 do
  if TPageControl(Control).Pages[I].TabIndex = TabIndex then
begin
  FillRect(Control.Canvas.Handle,aRect,Control.Canvas.Brush.Handle);
  // Do your text drawing here
  break;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this unit below, to fix Draw problems on Win64bits

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=292598

Comment: When answering a question, try to provide a full answer with sample code and a description. Just a link to another site is not enough.

Comment: Can you please include a piece of the solution in your answer? Or at least a high-level explanation of the solution in case that link ever becomes invalid.